# What is the main contributor of the color of honey?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, biochemistry, food-chemistry, color

I was told that the color of honey contains so much chemistry and that was interesting to me and after doing a couple of research I found that the color of honey depends on the presence of plant pigments including carotene, xanthophylls, anthocyanins, flavonoids, polyphenols, as well as amino acids and mineral salts. So as we can see there are many factors to the color of honey but my question is which out of all of the listed above is the main contributor and is the most affected by the increase in temperature (for example for acidity the main contributor is gluconic acid).

Comment: Barring your question being seen by someone with expertise in the matter of honey compositions, this appears to be too broad to get an answer.

Comment: Didn't you answer the question yourself based on your own findings: *color of honey depends on the presence of plant pigments including carotene, xanthophylls, anthocyanins, flavonoids, polyphenols, as well as amino acids and mineral salts*. This paper should suffice for your high school project. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/0005772X.1969.11097248

Comment: As I said in your previous posts, these questions are PhD level projects. Do you know how components are there in chocolate? Literally thousands. Natural products are very complicated.

Comment: I totally agree with you @M.Farooq but there is no specific one that is mostly affected by the temperature?

Comment: The paper is here which discusses color deterioration with temperature. Again it is dependent on honey source. It is related to HMF production. Read it https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00218839.1967.11100165

Comment: Years ago, the area I lived in had a wonderful independent small honey business, selling more than a dozen specific types of honey (sourced from different flowers). They had a wonderful range of colors specific to the type of flower. So, clearly the plant origins had a major impact. But, since they probably innumerable molecules that resulted in a given color would all age differently under temperature, attributing any color change to a few specific molecules seems impossible.

Comment: I appreciate all your valuable comments and @M.Farooq, I don't think I can access the article do I have to log in?

Comment: Also if anyone has any articles or journals that involve honey's acidity and color that would be very helpful and thanks again to everyone that tried to help.

Comment: You can investigate the dependence of the color of the different micronutrients you list on pH. Consider the sugars in honey as representing a relatively inert background. Consider also that the pH of honey does not vary all that much about its median value.

Answer (score 4):

> I found that the color of honey depends on the presence of plant
> pigments including carotene, xanthophylls, anthocyanins, flavonoids,
> polyphenols, as well as amino acids and mineral salts

Yes, you are right about that. The color differences is due to the difference in levels of minerals, anti-oxidants, and other trace elements that are present. In particular, levels of polyphenols, flavonoids, and carotenoid have been observed to have high correlation with color. Polyphenols are found in high concentration in darker honeys, whereas flavonoids are found in higher concentrations in lighter honeys.

**References**

1. *Antioxidant and antimicrobial capacity of several monofloral Cuban honeys and their correlation with color, polyphenol content and other chemical compounds* by Jose M.Alvarez-Suarez Sara Tulipani, Daimy Díaz, Yadiley Estevez, Stefania Romandini, Francesca Giampieri, Elisabetta Damiani, Paola Astolfi, Stefano Bompadre, Maurizio Battino, Volume 48, Issues 8–9, August–September **2010**, Pages 2490-2499, DOI: [https://doi.org/10.1016/j.fct.2010.06.021](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0278691510003959)
2. *Total Phenol, Antioxidant Activity, Flavonoids, Anthocyanins and Color of Honey as Affected by Floral Origin Found in the Arid and Semiarid Mediterranean Areas* by
   Taha M. Rababah  Mohamad Al‐Omoush  Susan Brewer  Mohammad Alhamad  Wade Yang  Mohammad Alrababah  Abd Al‐Majeed Al‐Ghzawi  Muhammad Al‐ u'datt  Khalil Ereifej  Fawzi Alsheyab  Ranya Esoh  Ali Almajwal, Volume38, Issue3, June **2014**, Pages 1119-1128, DOI: [10.1111/jfpp.12071](https://ifst.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/jfpp.12071)

Comment: Thank you very much, Nilay Ghosh, for the answer but do you mind by any chance sharing the references with me because I cannot access them.

Comment: @MoKamal I also do not have access to these papers. I only cited them for reference. If you like the answer, make sure to accept it(click the checkbox). It will be appreciated.